# Is there a way to act on objects before they're saved or updated in Django?

Tags: django, datetime, django-orm, django-models

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7046142/128967) recent question, I'll be needing to store all `datetime` objects in UTC, so I'll need to use a custom library to translate them properly before they're stored. Is there a way I can act on objects which are about to be saved and/or updated in order to convert the `datetime` objects to UTC? I'd like this to be pretty transparent to how I use Django, so if it's any one of these types of fields:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
event_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

...I'd like to translate them 'behind the scenes' so to speak, so as to not have to manually do the following:

```
new_instance.created = translate(now)
new_instance.modified = translate(now)
new_instance.event_time = translate(event_time)
```

It'd get pretty cumbersome pretty quickly to manually do this on all `DateTimeField` fields. Is there a way in Django to do this? In Hibernate, I'd either use AOP or an `Interceptor` to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about setting the [TIME_ZONE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#time-zone)?

To answer the question on the title, you can override the save method on your model:

```
def save(self):
    # do stuff before save
    super(YourModel, self).save()
    # do stuff after save
```

If you want to inform others about certain events (like pre-save and post-save), use django [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/)

Comment: If I set the `TIME_ZONE` to `UTC`, how can I detect what timezone to convert dates to? Do clients provide a timezone offset that I can use to translate dates to?

Comment: I tried this on my computer. For `auto_now` and `auto_now_add`, they are saved automatically to UTC time if you set TIME_ZONE to UTC (IIRC they calculated the difference with system timezone (for unix machine at least)). If you want users to have their own tz settings, then yes save the info to their UserProfile or something

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Signals: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if I understand you correctly, I think a good way to go will be to create a custom `DateTimeField`. For that you should subclass `DateTimeField` and override a few methods (to_python, pre_save, etc., it depends of your specific needs).

Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) for more info.